# Laravel object persistence between pages

Tags: php, object, laravel, controller, persistence

Here's my sample code.

```
class A {
  public function foo(){

 }

 public function bar(){
 }
}



class B {

  $one;
  function here(){
    $this->one = new A();
    $this->one->foo();
    return View::make("route1"); //This is ok, no problems
  }

  function there(){
    $this->one->bar(); //ERROR: Call to a member function bar() on a non-object
  }
}
```

My routes

```
Route::get("/one", B@here);
Route::get("/two", B@there);
```

Please these just show a sample. Its not the code proper.

When the first Route is called all is ok, and the corresponding page is loaded. Now on a button click which now requests the second page that error is thrown...

**//Call to a member function bar() on a non-object**

Its obvious the cause for this and I have been trying to see if Laravel offers a way to persist objects in between page calls and if someone can please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no nice way to store objects between page loads and really you would never want to do that anyway. A possible solution would be to add your dependency in the class constructor so it available throughout your class like this:

```
class A {
    public function foo(){}
    public function bar(){}
}

class B {
    protected $one;

    public function __construct(A $one)
    {
        $this->one = $one;
    }

    public function here()
    {
        $this->one->foo(); // Available
    }

    public function there()
    {
        $this->one->bar(); // Available
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this occurred to me, but sadly im not quite sure where or how Laravel will do an object instanciation since all calls are through a Route

Comment: @Cozzbie [Laravel IoC Container](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc) will handle injecting the dependency without you needing to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

Every request is a new application running with new variables in memory, so there is no persistence, you have to create your persistence code, if you need them

```
class B {

  $one;

  function here()
  {
    $this->one = new A();

    $this->one->foo();

    Session::put('one', $this->one); // persist it using Session

    return View::make("route1"); //This is ok, no problems
  }

  function there()
  {
    if (Session::has('one'))
    {
       $one = Session::get('one'); /// get your data back from session

       $one->bar();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Already tried persistence via sessions but that didnt work too. It keeps throwing the class instance error message that I showed. Thanks